# mysql - do not return row when value in NULL

Tags: mysql

When trying to select everything except when question_type!= 'A'; The row do not return data when question_type is NULL.

```
select * from table where question_type!= 'A';
```

Comment: Add in where `OR question_type IS NULL`

Answer (score 4):

So, include that in the `where` clause;

```
select t.*
from table t
where question_type <> 'A' or question_type is null;
```

Or, use the "null-safe" equal:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not question_type <=> 'A' ;
```

ANSI SQL implements `IS DISTINCT FROM` and `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.  The `<=>` operator is equivalent to `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.

Comment: The null-safe equal rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Return a value in case of `null` and go ahead:

```
select * from table where COALESCE(question_type, '') <> 'A';
```